# Pygame for-loop only runs once

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame

I'm making a platformer game. I have a list of platforms and then a " for platform in platform_list: ", that for loop only runs once, even though there are two platforms or more. i have another file where i store the platform class and the make_platform() function.

```py
###### platformer_main.py #######
from platform import make_platform

def platform_handler():
    print(len(platform_list)) # even if this prints out 2, the for loop still only runs once
    for platform in platform_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, green, (platform.x, platform.y, platform.w, platform.h))  # draw

        platform.x -= platform.speed  # move to the left
        if platform.done == False:  # add next platform
            if platform.x <= 650:
                platform.done = True
                add_platform()

        if platform.x + platform.w <= 0:  # delete platform
            platform_list.remove(platform)
            return platform_list
        # character collision detection
        if charac.x + charac.w >= platform.x and charac.x <= platform.x + platform.w and charac.y + charac.h >= platform.y and charac.y <= platform.y + platform.h:
            charac.fall = False
        else:
            charac.fall = True
        return charac
```

```py
###### platform.py #####

class Platform:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.w = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.speed = 0
        self.done = 0


def make_platform():
    platform = Platform()

    platform.x = 1000
    platform.y = random.randrange(200, 600)
    platform.w = random.randrange(300, 500)
    platform.h = 20
    platform.done = False
    platform.speed = 5

    return platform
```

no error messages occur.

Comment: Unindent `return charac` by one level. It's inside the for loop, so as soon as that line is reached, `charac` is returned, and the loop is automatically exited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` causes the function to, well, return, stopping any loop in progress.

Comment: ohh thanks, now i need to figure out how to do that for loop without return

Comment: You probably don't want to return until *after* the loop in finished, as @CalvinGodfrey pointed out.